# Analog phase shift/delay for PWM that keeps its duty cycle

Tags: analog, pwm, phase-shift, code-golf

I have a variable duty cycle PWM signal. Its frequency and duty cycle can change during the operation of the circuit.

I want to apply a deliberate phase shift/delay to it. In terms of phase, the delay will be fixed during the operation, but in terms of absolute time, it will have to vary as the PWM frequency varies.

[image]

My first instinct was to use a small MCU for this. It would measure the current frequency and duty cycle of the PWM input and then output something accordingly.

Then my gut feeling alarmed me that there probably is a very simple analog way of doing it with a couple of passives and a comparator or flip-flop, but all my tries so far have been unsuccessful and my online searches haven't dug up anything either.

So is there a simple analog way to perform this shifting operation?

### Numerical specs

- Deliberate Phase delay: 0...1 periods (aka -0.5...+0.5 periods)
- Delay accuracy and repeatability: ~0.1 period
- Duty cycle accuracy and repeatablity: ~0.01 period
- PWM frequency range: 1 decade (e.g. 100 kHz - 1 MHz)

Comment: How much delay, how much delay accuracy and repeatability? What range of PWM frequencies? Sounds like an MCU fits the bill better than analogue.

Comment: @Andyaka I added numerical specs. What I mean by that sentence, is that e.g. the phase change should be a constant e.g. 0.3 periods. But at 1 MHz that implies 300 ns shift, whereas at 500 kHz it would imply a 600 ns shift.

Comment: Is an FPGA out of the question? Dual port memory?

Comment: @winny sure an FPGA or MCU could do that easily. But say a device doesn't need one otherwise. I am wondering if there is a simple way to realize this function with passives, glue logic and analog, if no FPGA/MCU are available.

Comment: Use an MCU (and you probably realize that I'm an analogue engineer by now).

Comment: Vague thunklings: Generate a voltage from a ramp reset by each say positive main transistion. The mean value will increases with decreasing PWM frequency. || The output follows the input BUT is held off by a delay proportional to the derived analog signal - another ramp + comparator. The ramp rate in each case sets the offset. Similar for the falling edge delay - but my thunklings haven't fully derived that yet.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sounds interesting... I will relax the frequency range in the question a bit, because I believe it is too extreme to get the ramps to work over 3 decades.

Comment: Use an all-pass filter?